# Setting a MySQL field to another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a MySQL field called `description` and a field called `specs`. They need to be the same, but I only have `specs` filled out.

Can I do something like: `Update products set  description = specs;`?

Comment: think again, if `they need to be the same`, then u dun need the `description`

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS
   SET description = specs
```

...will set the `description` value to the same value as in the `specs` column, on a row by row basis for every row in the table.  Is that what you want for every record?

Why do you want to store redundant data in the `description` column?  Why not use only the `specs` column, and drop the `description` column from the table?